LateInitializationError: Field 'sharedPreferences' has not been initialized
i am trying to save user token when he is logging In but for some reason i keep getting this error and i added print statements at the start and end of my init() method to insure that the method is working correctly and they were both executed correctly:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await CacheHelper().init();
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class CacheHelper {
  static late final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

//here we initialize the cache
  Future<SharedPreferences> init() async {
    return sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  Future<bool> saveData({required String key, required dynamic value}) async {
    if (value is bool) {
      return await sharedPreferences.setBool(key, value);
    } else if (value is String) {
      return await sharedPreferences.setString(key, value);
    } else if (value is int) {
      return await sharedPreferences.setInt(key, value);
    } else {
      return await sharedPreferences.setDouble(key, value);
    }
  }
}

Future login() async {
  try {
    emit(LoginLoading());
    final response = await api.post(EndPoints.signIn, data: {
      ApiKey.email:
          signInEmail.text.isEmpty ? signUpEmail.text : signInEmail.text,
      ApiKey.password: signInPassword.text.isEmpty
          ? signUpPassword.text
          : signInPassword.text
    });
    final user = LoginModel.fromJson(response);
    CacheHelper().saveData(key: ApiKey.accessToken, value: user.accessToken);
    emit(LoginSuccess());
  } catch (e) {
    emit(LoginFailure(message: e.toString()));
  }
}


Try to change like this:
Future<void> init() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }


i tried your suggestion but it didn't solve the issue
